# How does SE sort the users who have the same number of edits in editor list?

Tags: support, users-page

We could see how many edits the users have in [editor list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors). How does SE sort the users who have the same number of edits?

Answer (score 2):

Like in all other places: random order, determined once then cached server side. (so it does not change every page refresh)

Took some effort to disprove [this guess](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253743/152859), but here we go.

Exhibit A: ([current monthly editors list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=month))

> [image]

Exhibit B: ([grgarside's last edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/222623/grgarside?tab=activity&sort=revisions))

> [image]

Exhibit C: ([Shog9's last edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=activity&sort=revisions))

> [image]

So, even though Shog last edit is way before grgarside, he is listed after him. Random order. Not sure how and when the server side cache reloads, but good chance that at some point, if those users won't make another edit, the order will change again.

Comment: How does this disprove the guess?  TZHX said whoever edited 9 posts first would be listed first, and that's the case here - grgarside's April 12 comes before shog's April 15.

Comment: @Troyen [Peter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen?tab=activity) reached 9 monthly edits only 20 hours ago, yet he appears first in the list. Unless I still miss something?

Comment: I see.  Your exhibits didn't mention Peter, and B and C are in the right order.

Comment: I did spend some time looking at the "Monthly" page, and then the "Weekly" page as well, and found absolutely no consistency on any measure I could imagine. I actually wrote an answer saying it looked random, before I noticed how it was apparently behaving for "all time". So this is as likely to be right.

Comment: @TZHX It seems that it is not ordered by the time when the users got to that position. You could see more to confirm it.